# Merge from greatest to least

Tags: java, merge

I'm trying to order a list of years from 2014 to 2010, but the merge I did organize them from 2010 to 2014. How can I change it?

This is comparator:

```java
import java.util.Comparator;
import mundoA.Registro;

public class RegistroComparadorA implements Comparator<Registro> {

  public int compare(Registro r1, Registro r2) {
    int rta = 0;
    if (r1.getAnio() >r2.getAnio()) {
      rta = 1;
    } else if (r1.getAnio() < r2.getAnio()) {
      rta = -1;
    } else {
      rta = r1.getWard().compareTo(r2.getWard());
    }
    return rta;
  }
}

  public NodoListaSencilla<T> merge(NodoListaSencilla<T> a, NodoListaSencilla<T> b) {
    NodoListaSencilla<T> dummyHead, curr; 
    dummyHead = new NodoListaSencilla<T>(a.getElemento()); 
    curr = dummyHead;
    while(a !=null && b!= null) {
      if(c.compare(a.getElemento(), b.getElemento())>0) { 

        curr.setSiguiente(b);
        b = b.getSiguiente();

      }
      else {             
        curr.setSiguiente(a); 
        a= a.getSiguiente();                      
      }
      curr = curr.getSiguiente();
    }
    curr.setSiguiente((a == null) ? b : a);
    return dummyHead.getSiguiente();
  }
```

Comment: When you call `merge`, are `a` and `b` already in the order you want (with later years first), or are they sorted with earlier years first?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, you are comparing elements `a` and `b` and setting the current element to `b` if the comparison is greater than zero. You should be setting it to `a` if you want higher years first.

Note that `Comparator` has utility functions that make it unnecessary to explicitly define `compare` in the way you are doing it. You could define your order as follows:

```
Comparator<Registro> order = Comparator
    .comparing(Registro::getAnio)
    .reversed()
    .thenComparing(Registro::getWard);
```

This seems more explicit to me.